# Grep - Output lines containing string on column 3

Tags: awk, grep

I'm trying to output lines that contain a specific string

example of lines:

```
Column1:Column2:Column3 + ID
Column1:Column2:Column3 - ID
Column1:Column2:Column3
```

desired output:

```
Column1:Column2:Column3 + ID
```

Attempts -

```
awk -F: '$3 == + ID' < file.txt > out.txt
```

which returns no output as it's searching for EXACTLY " + ID " without any other input within column3

Now I know I could do

```
grep -f " + ID" <file.txt >out.txt
```

but if + ID isn't within column3 then it will output any line containing + ID, example of this would be

output:

```
Column1:Column2 + ID:Column3
```

notice how + ID is within column2 and not 3

now I would also like to do this within a directory searching through all files and not just one specific .txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression match, anchored to the end of the field, in place of a string match:

```
awk -F: '$3 ~ /+ ID$/' < file.txt
Column1:Column2:Column3 + ID
```

or anchored to the end of the line, with `grep`:

```
grep '+ ID$' < file.txt
Column1:Column2:Column3 + ID
```

Comment: how can i use awk to search a folder of text files instead of one individual text file?

Comment: never mind i just used find  and then added awk to the command :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Pie '(Column\d:?){3} + ID$' file.txt > out.txt
```

if, for instance Column1: pattern repetition more than 3 then modify `{3,}` above

Answer (score 0):

This may be done through

```
find dir -type f -exec grep -H '+ ID$' {} +
```

This will find all regular files in or beneath the directory `dir` and then run `grep -H '+ ID$'` in batches of as many as possible of these. The result will contain both the filename of the file matching the regular expression and the lines from the file that matched.

To only get the filenames, use `-l` in place of `-H` with `grep`, and to only get the lines that match, use `-L` instead.

The regular expression `+ ID$` will match any line in a file that contains the exact string `+ ID` at the very end of the line.

Or, without `find` but with a `grep` that is able to recurse into subdirectories:

```
grep -R '+ ID$' dir
```

---

On systems that have a `grep` that does not do `-H` (this is a non-standard option), you may instead use

```
find dir -type f -exec grep '+ ID$' /dev/null {} +
```

If you just want the matching lines (and no file names) on a system like this, `cat` the files together and grep that:

```
find dir -type f -exec cat {} + | grep '+ ID$'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use substr like this:

```
awk '{ if (substr($0,position,length)=="+  ID" { print $0 } }' myfile.txt
```